# Overload function min and template

Tags: c++

My code is the following one :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  
#include <functional>  
#include <numeric>    
#include <cassert>


#include "image.h"
#include "..\Fct_numerique\fct_numerique.h"
    
template<typename Tim>
inline Tim min(const Image<Tim>& im){
    return( *std::min_element(im.begin(), im.end_element()) );
}
```

And it gives me the following errors which I don't understand:

> - Error   4   error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'  c:\pierre\prog\mylibim\sources\Fct_image\fct_manipulation_image_T.h 1164    1   test_dilatation_rapide
> - Error    5   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition c:\pierre\prog\mylibim\sources\Fct_image\fct_manipulation_image_T.h 1164    1   test_dilatation_rapide
> - Error    6   error C2059: syntax error : '::'    c:\pierre\prog\mylibim\sources\Fct_image\fct_manipulation_image_T.h 1164    1   test_dilatation_rapide
> - Error    7   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\pierre\prog\mylibim\sources\Fct_image\fct_manipulation_image_T.h 1164    1   test_dilatation_rapide

Comment: does it work with `#undef min`, or `inline Tim (min)(const Image<Tim>& im){` ?

Comment: What are those magical includes?

Answer (score 3):

You dont give information for a precise answer, we dont know where those error messages point to and what code is behind it.

But I will use my psychic powers and the clue that this seems to be Microsofts compiler. Thus I believe the correct question to be "Why are function macros for min/max a bad idea?", and the answer "because they will give you weird error messages".

Try adding these defines **before you include anything**

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#define NOMINMAX
#endif
```

Or set the define NOMINMAX in the project settings